# Access Azure blob storage from Web app with unc paths

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I currently have an on premise asp.net  web application that stores files in a network resource through UNC routes (\fileserver\storage$\docs...). since the validation is done through Active Directory, I do not have stored credentials on my app and is the IIS service account who have the permission to access the filer.

I am doing a migration test to Azure and I have created a web app service and a blob storage to host my resources, but when I try to access the storage, I receive a permission error to the blob storage route :exception in the application. Access to the path '\teststore.file.core.windows.net\appstorage' denied

It is possible to configure the Azure sandbox so that it can work in the same way as in the on premise without having to make changes in my code?

Thank you very much and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible currently I'm afraid. Azure Files expects you to provide the storage key to authenticate to the share. There is a preview for using AD accounts to access Azure Files (using Azure AD Domain Services) but this wouldn't help you here, as your web app would need to be domain joined, which is not possible.

FYI your not using Blob here, your using files which sits on top of Blob. Actual blob storage also has a [preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/announcing-the-preview-of-aad-authentication-for-storage/) of using Azure AD accounts to access it, but this would entail you changing your code to make blob calls.

Either way, it would be a code change.

Comment: you can enable managed identity on webapp so it should be possible using Azure AD account???

Comment: Talking to blob storage using managed identity should be possible, but would still require code changes to talk directly to blob. Files, however, is not AAD, it is a hybrid approach using AAD DS, user needs to exist in AAD DS and managed identities do not get synced.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense :-)